# Leopard gecko's eye problem - eyelids have grown closed

Tags: health, reptiles, leopard-geckos, lizards

I have a leopard gecko which was given to me by someone. Her eyelids seem to have grown closed. I was told it was her shedding that didn't come off correctly and have done as suggested in this case by swabbing the eyes with water and keeping her in humid conditions. No improvement has been marked.

I did google photos of what retained eye caps look like and hers look much more severe than this, as it seems her eyelids are immobile and stuck on her eyes. She is very healthy otherwise and always eats well.

Please advise me on what to do as I would really like to help her.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are really worried, I would take them to an exotic vet. They will be able to tell you for sure if it is a retained eye cap, something like a calcium deposit or a different disorder. They will also be able to give you prescription or normal eye drops for your pet.

If you aren't particularly worried about it, you can try to wait until their next shed and see if it comes off during that shed. A lot of people do that for retained eye caps in snakes. It isn't life threatening if it is a cap, but please note that my experience comes from snakes and it could be different for leopard geckos. If it is still there after the next shed, you should probably take them to a vet.

Make sure to keep your humidity at a correct level, to keep them watered, and keep the temperatures correct. Usually if it is a retained eye cap, it will come off normally

EDIT: yours looks fairly bad. I would err on the side of being safe by taking it to a vet. I'm sure all they'll do is give you some drops and call it good (assuming it is an eye cap issue), but it would be good to have the gecko checked to make sure, considering the severity of the case - and especially if you don't know when the last shed was.

Comment: I wouldn't wait for next shed, retained eye caps will severely damage the eye if untreated. The next she will takes weeks which is a long time to wait.

Comment: Not sure about leos but for snakes a stuck cap doesnt damage the snake according to breeders forums. It is nice to take off using a humid hide and a q tip but it is not necessary to take off.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that treatment of a retained cap has the possibility to do more damage to the eye than leaving it depending on how zealous you are and what techniques you use. It also stresses the animal out a lot each time you attempt to get it off. If you do it yourself, be careful. If you take it to a vet they can tell you what to do for sure

Comment: I also read it as the person before them said it was from a shed and that they havent seen a shed yet meaning there is an unknown amount of time before next shed but it sounds like the current shed wasn't terribly recent. It would be good to check when the shed was last if they remember.

Comment: Ya, retained eye caps in snakes as well damage the eye. I've seen it in practice a few times, the vet had to remove it with moist cotton balls, saline flush and Q-tips. The worst I've seen left a huge dent in its eye.

Comment: Only if the eye caps are retained through multiple shedding cycles or if they have an underlying infection already in the eye, which is why i said if that happens again take them to the vet. Usually either of those is accompanied by lack of appetite and other problems though. I have never ever heard of a single retained cap causing severe damage to the eye unless it was retained because of an infection that was already there. If multiple are left on the eye it can definitely cause problems (and indicate problems)

Comment: and as a person that has had multiple ball pythons go through retained eye caps and the info from forums, fixing temps/humid and waiting for shed works most of the time. Not saying you should, but to say it will severely damage the eye is an overstatement

Comment: Also dents in eyes are a symptom of bad humidity in bp's. Usually happens when humidity is too low and they can go away after re hydrated.

Comment: No this was an ulcer, not your dehydrated dent. I get what your saying but when it comes to eyes I personally would rather take care of it asap than wait.